# I want to check whether my list contains some values using an anonymous class

Tags: java, data-structures

I have a list structure of some class; let's say `List<Client> myList;`.
`Client` has fields like `name` and `passwd`.
If I want to check if my list contains a class with those, how can I check it? Because I am trying to use `myList.contains(new Client(name,surname))`, and it seems not to be working.

```
for(DBClient client : register.getALl()){
     System.out.println(client);
}
System.out.println(check[0]+" "+check[1]);
if(register.getALl().contains(new DBClient(check[0],check[1]))){
```

Should I check all variables of the class to be equal to my variables or is it possible to check it somehow?

Comment: have you implemented equals() method in the Client class?

Comment: I don't see an anonymous class.

Answer (score 2):

That is JDK ArrayList implemention inside contain(Object t)

```
public int indexOf(Object o) {
    if (o == null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            if (elementData[i]==null)
                return i;
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            if (o.equals(elementData[i]))
                return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

so, it depends on your Object’s equal() method.

Answer (score 0):

As @dirch has suggested, it depends on the equals() method. By default Object.equals() compares only the object reference. If you want to override this behavior you may want to override the equals() method in FirstDup class as follows

```
public boolean equals (Object dup) {

    return this.name.equals(((DBClient)dup).getName()) && this.surName.equals(((DBClient)dup).getSurName());

}
```